# Installed dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1 Can't boot into Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 14.04, windows-8, bootloader

I have two internal hard drives; 1 for Windows 8.1 and 1 for storage. I decided to install Ubuntu on the secondary hard drive. One of the guides I used advised me to make a small boot partition in the free space as well, so I did. After my installation my computer defaults to the Ubuntu partition and I cannot boot to Windows 8.1.

This is the error Windows gives me:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \boot\bcd

  Status: 0xc000000f

  Info: The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors.
```

What I've tried:
- First, yes I have been Googling for an hour now.
- I tried to boot from my Windows hard drive thinking that since I selected a bootloader on the secondary hard drive during installation.
- The message also recommended I insert my installation disk and "repair my computer" I ran the programs and no luck.

Please, does anyone know how I could restore my Windows partition? (At least have me get in so I can run **EasyBCD**.)

**EDIT:**
I have just installed *Grub-Customizer* and the only options available to me are for Ubuntu. Could this possibly be because the Windows Bootloader is on the other hard driver? GParted shows that it is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How far can you get into your recovery disc? If you can enter CMD, you can follow [this guide](http://fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/12/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-in-windows-8/). This will reinstall the Windows 8 boot loader onto your primary hard drive's MBR.

*Usually I'd include the steps upon posting, but the post is too long. Let me know how you get on, or how far you get, and if a success, I will rewrite the instructions into this post.*

Comment: This seems to be the solution, however, I made it down the guide until I got to cd /d  the folder was not found. I have selected previously the volume that was 300MB and labeled system. Another thing I should mention is that in the guide, it says all file systems should be fat32. For some reason both hard drives of mine are NTFS. Don't know if that makes a different or not.

Comment: No, the guide says that the EFI partition should be FAT32. Not all file systems. Also, the `/d` should be a `/D`, though it should work lower/uppercase (I think) as the `/D` switch is to change the working drive in addition to changing the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against EasyBCD. I have a UEFI enabled Dell Inspiron Laptop that came pre-loaded with Windows 8.

I thought EasyBCD would solve my problems, and it did, for a while anyway. However - it (EasyBCD) does not clean up after itself if (and when) you ever make changes to your Linux side of things.

For example, when I updated from Ubuntu 13.10 to 12.04, EasyBCD did not roll with the changes well at all. Made booting to Linux a nightmare.  Trying to modify settings within EasyBCD only complicated matters.  I simply do not use EasyBCD any more.

For any booting issues, I rely more on the Ubuntu Boot Repair CD.