# How do you repair a non-booting Windows 8.1 installation after updating to Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 14.04, windows-8

I have dual boot set-up with Windows 8.1(original OS) and Ubuntu 14.10.

Recently, Windows stopped booting. I am presented with a 'Recovery' screen with the Error Code: 0xc0000225.

Windows stopped working around the same time that I upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04.

How do I repair the Windows partition?

Also, I think I used to have a 'Recovery' options available in the Grub menu.
However, I attempted to run boot-repair first and now I only have 4 options:
  Ubuntu
  Ubuntu with advanced options
  Windows
  System Setup
Is there a way to return the 'Windows Recovery' option to the Grub menu?

Comment: I believe the answer is at this same question http://askubuntu.com/questions/463581/installed-dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-and-windows-8-1-cant-boot-into-windows?rq=1